# PHP file_get_contents() fails intermittently and occasionally

Tags: php, email, file-get-contents

On my company's site I use file_get_contents() at various places to retrieve a complete web page (from the same site) which I then put into a PDF that I download to the user. For some mysterious reason, occasionally it doesn't work. I've tried specifying both an absolute path and a URL, with the same results. From time to time it returns nothing. Not even an error return. Since it seems random, intermittent, and occasional, I'm wondering if it is some sort of timing-sensitive issue. What could be happening? How might I find out what's going on? It's only occasional but frequent enough that users complain. The call is in proximity to a subsequent call to mail() to send the PDF, if that could be a factor.

Comment: do you use a relative absolute urI?

Comment: use `curl` ....

Comment: What does fail and it doesn't work mean?

Comment: We need some code, preferably the one that fails occasionnaly where you are using the `file_get_contents` and you may probably want to check the logs, you may find something interesting to share with us.

Comment: inorder to know the error make sure that you have commented out `error_reporting(0);`on top of your php file

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, perform [file_exists](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) before attempting to read the contents of the file, this is just to ensure the file exists. Secondly, [file_get_contents](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will return false in the event of a failure, I would also check that as well. As a final check, it's entirely possible that the file you are attempting to read could be empty. Since [file_get_contents](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) returns a string (if there is contents), you could perform a [strlen](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) check to ensure that the file does, in fact, have contains.

If [file_get_contents](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is returning null, this indicates the file is empty and there could be an underlying problem somewhere in your application. If the file you are attempting to read is created by your application, revisit the code which creates the file to ensure that the files are, in fact, being populated with contents before writing.

Comment: I just realized that I was using an absolute file path and yet the file seemed to be processed as if it were a web page, that is, the PHP code was executed. How is that possible? Does an absolute path for a file get parsed as a web page with file_get_contents? I put in a URL instead, which has not worked before, but so far it seems to be working. Very puzzling that this works fine 95% of the time, but the other 5% of the time it silently returns nothing.

Comment: file_get_contents will literally return the contents of any file which it is given. You may also pass it a url to a webpage; in this instance it will return the compiled web source of the webpage, similar if you view the source of a webpage in a web browser. If you want it to return a file, maybe a PDF? Then you need to point file_get_contents to the absolute/relative path to the file. For me to help any further, a code snippet will be a great help